# Are answers that address the (im)plausibility of a claim acceptable when proof cannot be obtained?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This recent question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9999/4020) about a Korean orphan run-away is probably impossible to prove one way or another.

The OP comments:

> ...if there was some documentation available that he lived in an orphanage that would be superb. Without that, I'll probably never be truly convinced, but if there is other evidence that will have to do. I would love to see some police reports, or even witness testimony from someone who purchased gum from a homeless 5-year old boy in the area where he claimed to live around 1995.

This seems to be a request for verification of plausibility, as seeing a 5-year-old boy selling gum is not proof of the claim, but only proof of plausibility.

Likewise, documentation of Korean orphan runaways might qualify as verification of plausibility.

As much as I laugh at Mythbusters, one thing I think they have right is three possible answers to each challenge: Confirmed, Busted, or Plausible.

So I guess I'm asking if the third option of "Plausible" ought to be considered acceptable on this site when a definite answer cannot be obtained.

Comment: @Fabien: Care to comment/answer here, since your recent re-deletion of my answer indicates you think these sorts of answers should not be permitted?